# parallel.foreach and perfmon reported threads

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, perfmon

I have an application that reads from a text file that contains 100s-1000s of lines.

Each line is processed using a parallel.foreach using the ParallelOptions to restrict the amount of tasks fired off. This is the "controller" task.

Within this "controller" parallel.foreach is another parallel.foreach which will perform the actual work. Each controller task fired off will perform the same work, with the different data input as specified in the original file line. Again this work parallel.foreach is using a paralleloptions to restrict the amount of tasks fired off.

In my last test, I used
Controller foreach: MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4
Worker foreach: MaxDegreeOfParallelism:4

Which according to my maths, should mean that there is a maxium of 16 tasks working at any one time.

However, when I check the perfmon.exe, I can see my application using 700 threads. After a few more hours this will be over 1000.

How can this be? Why doesn't the GC collect these finished threads?

Previously, my code was firing off actual threads within a Thread[] with the same problem. Then I moved it to a Task[] and had the same problem. I assumed there was a thread leak somewhere and a reference was still pointing to the thread/ task. I have spent many hours searching for this to no avail.

So I moved to a parallel.foreach with the thinking that if I never have a reference to the task been created, a task leak cannot oocur, as it all happens within a lamda.

But the problem persists. Any ideas on why this is? Or is it normal?

Added the code below, it is a bit of a mess due to all tests and trying to debug this problem, have tried to clean it up a bit.

```
public static void RunActions(
    List<paramsActionSettings> listActions,
    string[] arrList,
    int numThreads,
    string domain = null,
    delGetParamsActionSettings delGetActionsList = null,
    delProcessString callbackActionsComplete = null
    )
{

    int iCntr= 0;
    int iTotal = arrList.Length;


    ParallelOptions prlOptions = new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numThreads
    };

    //foreach (string listItemIter in arrList)
    object oLock = new object();
    Parallel.ForEach(arrList, prlOptions,(listItemIter) =>
    {
        lock (oLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting "+iCntr + " of " + iTotal + " run actions");
            iCntr++;
        }

        string listItemCopySafe = string.Copy(listItemIter);

        bool bCanDo = true;
        List<paramsActionSettings> listActionsUse;
        if (listActions == null)
        {
            listActionsUse = delGetActionsList();
        }
        else
        {
            listActionsUse = listActions;
        }
        foreach (paramsActionSettings prms in listActionsUse)
        {
            if (prms.delCanDo != null && !prms.delCanDo(listItemCopySafe, domain))
            {
                bCanDo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bCanDo) return;


        List<paramsFire> listParams = new List<paramsFire>();

        //create a list of paramsfire objects, the object holds the params and the delfunction
        foreach (paramsActionSettings prms in listActionsUse)
        {
            listParams.Add(new paramsFire(prms.delGetDoParams(listItemCopySafe), prms.delDoSomething));
        }


        FireActions(listParams, callbackActionsComplete, listItemCopySafe);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished " + iCntr + " of " + iTotal );
    }); 
}



private static void FireActions(List<paramsFire> list, delProcessString callbackActionsComplete, string itemArr)
{
    int icntr = 0;
    foreach (paramsFire prms in list)
    {
        try
        {
            if (icntr == 0) 
            {
                if (!prms.delDoSomething(prms.oParams))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                prms.delDoSomething(prms.oParams); 
            }
            icntr++;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteLine("foreach (paramsFire prms in list)");
            UtilException.Dump(e, "foreach (paramsFire prms in list)");
        }
    } 
     if (callbackActionsComplete != null)
    {
        try
        {
            callbackActionsComplete(itemArr);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code. Unanswerable without. And test it in a small app to make sure no other threads are created.

Comment: I asked for the code but this is nearly undecipherable. Maybe one of the DoSomethings deadlocks, do you see all the `Finished " + iCntr` statements? And remove the `catch{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the problem is not with any particular API as you said that the problem is the same for threads, tasks and `Parallel.ForEach`.

Don't ask why the framework is not doing its job (because it is). Ask, why your code is spawning more threads than you intended. Without seeing more code this is issue cannot be fully answered.

Comment: Definiately, there is something in my understanding missing here, as you say, it happens regardless of the multi threading type used. However, I have logged the parallel starting and finishing it's run, this to my (admitted) limited understanding should mean it gets clean up, not hang around many hours later using up 1000s of threads.

Comment: Where in your code are you counting the number of concurrent threads? The second time you read iCounter you will get a different (wrong) value on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

I did a slight bit of rewriting. It only got up to 22 threads on my machine (8 proc box). Feel free to employ any of these changes:

```
    public static void RunActions(
        IEnumerable<paramsActionSettings> listActions,
        IEnumerable<string> arrList,
        int numThreads,
        string domain = null,
        delGetParamsActionSettings delGetActionsList = null,
        delProcessString callbackActionsComplete = null)
    {

        var cntr = 0;
        var total = arrList.Count();

        var prlOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numThreads
        };

        ////foreach (var listItemIter in arrList)
        Parallel.ForEach(arrList, prlOptions, listItemIter =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref cntr);
            Console.WriteLine("starting " + cntr + " of " + total + " run actions");

            var listItemCopySafe = string.Copy(listItemIter);

            var listActionsUse = listActions ??
                ((delGetActionsList == null) ? new paramsActionSettings[0] : delGetActionsList());
            var canDo = listActionsUse.All(prms => prms.delCanDo == null
                || prms.delCanDo(listItemCopySafe, domain));

            if (!canDo)
            {
                return;
            }

            var listParams = listActionsUse.Select(prms => new paramsFire(
                prms.delGetDoParams(listItemCopySafe),
                prms.delDoSomething));

            // create a list of paramsfire objects, the object holds the params and the delfunction
            FireActions(listParams, callbackActionsComplete, listItemCopySafe);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished " + cntr + " of " + total);
        });
    }

    private static void FireActions(
        IEnumerable<paramsFire> list,
        delProcessString callbackActionsComplete,
        string itemArr)
    {
        var icntr = 0;

        foreach (var prms in list)
        {
            try
            {
                if (icntr == 0)
                {
                    if (!prms.delDoSomething(prms.oParams))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    prms.delDoSomething(prms.oParams);
                }

                icntr++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorLog.WriteLine("foreach (paramsFire prms in list)");
                UtilException.Dump(e, "foreach (paramsFire prms in list)");
            }
        }

        if (callbackActionsComplete == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            callbackActionsComplete(itemArr);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, but how about eliminating `var listItemCopySafe = string.Copy(listItemIter);` ? It's totally useless.